# MySQL - Case-insensitive search

Tags: php, mysql, search, letters

Building my search engine for users to search for three variables $Title, $Text and $Number...
How do i make it when user searches it finds all results no matter the case type (lower or upper case) user typed in $query?

```
$query = trim ($query);

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts
        WHERE (`Number` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Text` LIKE '%".$query."%') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). Moreover, I can't see you use `mysql_real_escape_string` and escape all instances of `_` and `%`.

Comment: Still, this question has to do with the query, not the method by which the query is called.

Comment: @CaptainFord: That's why I posted my remark as a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Use case insensitive [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collate.html)

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE (`Number` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
OR (`Title` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
OR (`Text` LIKE '%".$query."%')
COLLATE utf8_ci  --'ci' stands for case insensitive: choose the colaltion that fits your encoding
```

List of supported collations is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the mysql [LOWER()](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_function_upper_lower.php) function:

```
$query=strtolower($query); //Query to lower case
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts
    WHERE (LOWER(`Number`) LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (LOWER(`Title`) LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (LOWER(`Text`) LIKE '%".$query."%') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

However, mysql function in php are deprecated, you should use mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: This snippet does not provide any protection against injection attacks.

Comment: @mickmackusa Nor does the one in the question. The question was on how to deal with case insensitive search and the answer focuses on that. One could also argue that the `mysql_*` api has been deprecated in php5 and removed in php7, but again that wasn't the scope of the question. In fact both issues have already been addressed in the question's comments :)

Comment: It is okay for questions to have faulty code (we want OPs to post their attempt as a form of respect to volunteers, provide context, and potentially narrow the scope of the issue.  On the other hand, answers are expected to contain best practices and high quality insights. If you have time to improve this old answer, please do so for the betterment of SO.  My initial comment was only to warn copy-pasta developers that they should not copy-pasta this answer.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL is case-insensitive for `char`, `varchar`, and `text`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) (non-binary strings) by default.

Comment: Depends on the default collation. See the link in Mchl's answer.

Answer (score -1):

One thing I've done in my own database for a company is made everything uppercase with the strtoupper() function in PHP (specifically for personal security reasons). It would also help if you use the utf8_ci collation in your fields that you want to be case-insensitive.

Comment: This will remove all formatting from text so for things like title it's bad solution.